# Create a filterin GSheet per Scriptin

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try to create a simply script to filter a bigger list.

When I am using the command "ss.getRange('1:1904').createFilter();" the script runs perfect but when I try to work with a variable the script do not run.

```js
function myScript() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("MyUsers");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow()
  ss.getRange('1:1904').createFilter();   //<< the script runs perfect
  ss.getRange(1, lr).createFilter();      //<< the script to not run
  
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().whenTextDoesNotContain('Peking').build();
  ss.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(11, criteria);
  
  //ss.getRange('2:1904').activate();

  //ss.deleteRows(ss.getActiveRange().getRow(), ss.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
  ss.getFilter().remove();
};
```

I am sure the is only a simply bug, but I do not have any idea where is the fault.

Who can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- In the case of `ss.getRange('1:1904')`, the rows from 1 to 1940 are used for all columns. On the other hand, in the case of `ss.getRange(1, lr)`, only one cell is used. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

If you want to set the basic filter from row 1 to the last row with all columns, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
ss.getRange(1, lr).createFilter();
```

#### To:

```
ss.getRange(1, 1, lr, ss.getMaxColumns()).createFilter();
```

- If you want to use the data range, you can use `ss.getDataRange().createFilter();`.

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: @J. Doe About `Many thanks it works perfect.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer